# How to use Roboguice to inject subclasses?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, guice, roboguice

Documentation on this is hard to come by. This is an advance use of Roboguice involving libraries.

Say I have a class in my base library called MyRoboActivity which extends from RoboActivity

```
@Inject
HumanModel humanModel;
```

In one project for men just say, I would like the above to be populated with this version

```
@Singleton
public class MaleModel extends HumanModel {...}
```

In another project for women, I would the above to be injected with this version

```
@Singleton
public class FemaleModel extends HumanModel {...}
```

What syntax do I need in each male and female projects to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out using Roboguice Modules - http://knowledge.lapasa.net/?p=986